# OAuth1 WP-API signature does not match

Tags: python, wordpress, oauth, sha1, hmac

I'd like to add posts to WP with python 3.5 using WP-API v2. I've done the first two steps of the authentication (I got the final tokens) with POSTMAN, and now I got stuck with the implementation. If I try to create a new post (it works with postman) I get the following result:

```
{"code":"json_oauth1_signature_mismatch","message":"OAuth signature does not match","data":{"status":401}}
```

The code that I use for signing is:

```
def sign_request(base, key):
    from hashlib import sha1
    import hmac

    hashed = hmac.new(key.encode(), base.encode(), sha1)

    return binascii.b2a_base64(hashed.digest())[:-1].decode('utf-8')
```

The base format I use is: POST&url&params

The key is: clientsecret&token

According to the [documentation](http://oauth1.wp-api.org/docs/basics/Signing.html)

Any ideas?